# Teltonika FM1100 GPS Device sending same Data repeatedly after ack

Tags: php, tcp, gps, socketserver

I have a teltonika FM1100 device am developing web user interface for the device PHP

device was sending data through connection using TCP
am able to get data from the device like

1. First device send IMEI number
2. after that i send acknowledgment (01) to the FM100 device to start send data
3. then am receiving the raw data after that i parsed the received data
4. then again am sending no of data Element i received (ex:06) in integer as acknowledgement data to the FM1100 device.

   but the FM1100 device keeps sending the same data repeatedly 
   am not sure am sending the correct acknowledgement data to FM1100 device or is any problem with device please help how to solve the issue

Comment: hey, i am struggling with sending the acknowledgment 01. I already tried "\x01" and "\x00\x01" but both don't work. What did you use? thanks

Comment: @DrazenMokic pack("i", "01")

Comment: hi kanan- how did you created a handshake with teltonika device - i have FMB010. It is sending IMEI number but not moving ahead from it.

Answer (score 0):

You should send integer value with correct endianess - for Teltonika it's big endian:

```
fwrite($socket, pack('N', 0x06));
```

Comment: can you please elaborate?